# custom sort on oracle sql data set for Days

Tags: sql, oracle, sql-order-by

I have below Set of Data for each particular ID

```
No     Id
1      1
2      1
3      1
4      1
1      2
2      2
3      2
4      2
```

I want to sort No column with desired sort for Example If i want to start from Second Row of Each Id
Data will display like this

```
No     Id
2      1
3      1
4      1
1      1
2      2
3      2
4      2
1      2
```

And So On if want to start with any of row it will be sorted like above

Comment: That's a nice question to ask. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

One option would be using `SIGN()` function in such a way

```
ORDER BY id, SIGN(no - 1) DESC, no
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=9f976275d4093939da302752bdf89e97)</kbd>

**Edit** : in the case the `no` value needed to start from varies, then use convert the ORDER BY expression to the following along with a substituion variable such as

```
ORDER BY id, SIGN(no - &start + 1) DESC, no
```

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=dc12dbd7690872d1f0734f27cf150c1b)</kbd>

Comment: in case i want to start from 3 output must be
`No     Id
3      1
4      1
1      1
2      1
3      2
4      2
1      2
2      2`

Comment: depends on what you exactly need and want @AdeelAslam , I replied depending on the case within the question.

Comment: you have gave a good option however i want to sort from any starting no by keep sequence of other number same

Answer (score 0):

To start from 2nd row try Query#1 and Query#2 to start from the third row.

```
 create table mytable(No int, Id int);
 
 insert into mytable values(1,      1);
 insert into mytable values(2,      1);
 insert into mytable values(3,      1);
 insert into mytable values(4,      1);
 insert into mytable values(1,      2);
 insert into mytable values(2,      2);
 insert into mytable values(3,      2);
 insert into mytable values(4,      2);
```

Query#1

```
 with cte as 
 (  
   select no,id,row_number()over(partition by id order by rownum)rn from 
  (
   select no,id from mytable where no=2
   union all
   select no,id from mytable where no<2
  )t 
 )select no,id from cte
```

Output:

| NO | ID |
| --- | --- |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 2 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 |

Query#2:

```
 with cte as 
 (  
   select no,id,row_number()over(partition by id order by rownum)rn from 
  (
   select no,id from mytable where no=3
   union all
   select no,id from mytable where no<3
  )t 
 )select no,id from cte
```

Output:

| NO | ID |
| --- | --- |
| 3 | 1 |
| 4 | 1 |
| 1 | 1 |
| 2 | 1 |
| 3 | 2 |
| 4 | 2 |
| 1 | 2 |
| 2 | 2 |

*db<fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=77a104e97a71d8c9cba5abafcf9819d7)*